# Adbdinsecure and Droid Explorer

Tags: droid-explorer

I have two phones, a Doogee X5max and a Cubot Gt88, both fully rooted. (Root explorer fully functional on phone). Without Adbd insecure installed and ticked both phones behave the same in Droid Explorer for PC. i.e.I can't access the data folder and I can't modify files or folders. When I install Adbd insecure and apply the patch to the Cubot it works perfectly. Droid explorer has full access and the consol prompt changes from a $ to a #. However, if I install Adbd insecure on the Doogee and apply the patch I immediately lose all connection with the phone. It shows up in Device manager as unknown device with a code 43 error. I can't reconnect to it until I have removed the patch and re-booted the phone.
  The failing Doogee X5max has Busybox installed, Usb Debugging enabled, Oem unlocking enabled, the google ADB drivers installed and the OEM driver installed. There seems to be a conflict between the Doogee and Adbd insecure that upsets Windows. Any clues?